# angular 5 validation date field using form builder

Tags: angular, validation, angular5, formbuilder, angular-validator

i have form and i want to validate date field on submit, i am using Form Builder, how can i do this(the angular way) ?
another problem why i cant see the value published_date in the date field ?
i tried to search and i can't find solution for input date field.

```js
unamePattern = /^\d{1,2}\/\d{1,2}\/\d{4}$/;
  ngOnInit() {
    this.book = 
      {
        id: 55,
        author_name : "vv",
        published_date :  new Date('01/02/2018'),
        title : "cc"
      };
      
      this.form = this.formBuilder.group({
        title : ['', Validators.required],
        author : ['', Validators.required],
        datePublish: ['', Validators.pattern(this.unamePattern)],
        }
      );
  }
```

```html
<input 
            [(ngModel)]="book.published_date"
            id="dateOfBirth" 
            class="form-control" 
            placeholder="yyyy-mm-dd" 
            name="dp" 
            ngbDatepicker 
            formControlName="datePublish"
            #dp="ngbDatepicker">
            
          <div class="input-group-append">
            <button class="btn btn-outline-secondary" (click)="dp.toggle()" type="button">
                <i class="fa fa-calendar" aria-hidden="true"></i>
            </button>
          </div>
```

Answer (score 3):

If you could use [`momemt()`](https://momentjs.com/) then it will very easy to get hands on date time things and you could write your own validator as

```
import {AbstractControl} from '@angular/forms';
import * as moment from 'moment';

export class YourValidator {
  static dateVaidator(AC: AbstractControl) {
    if (AC && AC.value && !moment(AC.value, 'YYYY-MM-DD',true).isValid()) {
      return {'dateVaidator': true};
    }
    return null;
  }
}
```

And in your form object you could use it like

```
import {YourValidator} from "....";

this.form = this.formBuilder.group({
    title : ['', Validators.required],
    author : ['', Validators.required],
    datePublish: ['', Validators.compose([Validators.required, YourValidator.dateVaidator])],
});
```

[**Demo stackblitz.com/angular-date-validator**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-date-validator?embed=1&file=src/app/shared/date.validator.ts)

Comment: when  i try to insert text instead the date, it's still validate. i don't know why

Comment: @Asafshay I have added demo link to test above validator have a look at [*stackblitz.com/angular-date-validator*](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-date-validator?embed=1&file=src/app/shared/date.validator.ts)

Answer (score 1):

For date validation you can use [ng4-validators](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng4-validators#date-1).

```
npm i ng4-validators --save
```

Import and use:

```
import { CustomValidators } from 'ng4-validators';

ngOnInit() {
  this.book = 
    {
      id: 55,
      author_name : "vv",
      published_date :  new Date('01/02/2018'),
      title : "cc"
    };

    this.form = this.formBuilder.group({
      title : ['', Validators.required],
      author : ['', Validators.required],
      datePublish: ['', CustomValidators.date,
      }
    );
  }
```

Comment: The project is now deprecated, you should now use https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-custom-validators . But otherwise, that's the answer I was looking for.

Comment: It doesn't allow custom format. British format for example: DD/MM/YYYY